# Copy and print text inside iframe by watir webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I want to copy text inside iframe by watir webdrive and print it. iframe is inside a div.
Both iframe and div have ID.

```
<div id="sitbReaderKindleSample" style="visibility: visible; width: 497.5px;    height: 18138px;">
    <iframe id="sitbReaderFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="height:  17945px;">
</div>
```

my code is

```
targetURL = "https://www.amazon.in/Secret-Druids-Christopher-C-Doyle-  ebook/dp/B01BMD4JF0?ie=UTF8&qid=1472664339&ref_=lp_1318158031_1_2&s=books&sr=1"

browser.goto targetURL
browser.image(:id => "ebooksSitbLogoImg").click 
itext = browser.div(:id => 'sitbReaderKindleSample').text
 puts itext
```

OUTPUT is

> End of this sample Kindle book.
>   Enjoyed the preview?
>   Buy now

or even:

> See details for this book in the Kindle Store

but i do not need this. This is from outside iframe. i need the text inside iframe.

I tried

```
itext = browser.iframe(:id => 'sitbReaderFrame').text
```

its output is blank

Need help to print the text inside the iframe

I use rubymine IDE

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in doing:

```
browser.iframe(:id => 'sitbReaderFrame').text
```

If you are getting an empty `String`, that means you are using an older version of Watir:

- In Watir-Webdriver v0.9.1 (and prior): `iframe.text` returned the text nodes of the `iframe` element, which is always nothing.
- In Watir-Webdriver v0.9.2 (and later): `iframe.text` was changed to switch to the `iframe` context and then return its `body` text (which is what you want).

You should make sure that you are using the latest version.

Comment: it works after updating and by using when_present(90

Answer (score 0):

itext = browser.iframe(:id => 'sitbReaderFrame').body.text

This works for me, adding the body to the chain.